# "Unable to activate" ruby gem: dependencyissue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a noob to run gem dependencies. I get this error when trying to run a ruby program

```
.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2064:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate familysearch-0.4.2, because faraday-0.9.1 conflicts with faraday (~> 0.8.4), multi_json-1.11.2 conflicts with multi_json (~> 1.5.0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

In trouble shooting, I installed Bundler. Here is what my lock file looks like:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    rack (1.6.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  faraday (~> 0.9.1)
  nokogiri
  rack (~> 1.1)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.5
```

I found similar stuff over the webs and their solutions. Unfortunately, none of these worked for me. Thank you for looking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem you're having issues with, familysearch-0.4.2, hasn't been updated since March of 2014. Hence, it's dependent on old gem versions.

I'd recommend submitting an issue to the Gem created, jimmyz, on Github via https://github.com/jimmyz/familysearch-rb/issues/new.

While the VCR tests for the gem aren't working (so I couldn't check my work), try using my forked version of the gem below where I updated the dependencies.

```
gem "familysearch", git: 'https://github.com/acpk/familysearch-rb.git'
```

Comment: That was a rockstar comment and work. Thank you!!! That got rid of one of them problems, I tied to use and then emulate your fix but I still get: Unable to activate familysearch-0.4.2, because multi_json-1.11.2 conflicts with multi_json (~> 1.5.0) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: @kinezu - Just updated it. Features may be broken though, as I couldn't test the gem on the fly due to due to VCR.